# Custom locale in Android

Tags: android, localization, locale

the Android phones in Slovakia have a custom locale - en_SK and cs_SK. Language is either Czech or English, location is Slovakia. Now I would like to have strings that target these locales. The default approach is to create a folder "values-CountryCode", for Czech Republic it's values-cs.

But I get a build error if I add a folder name values-en_SK or values-cs_SK:
"invalid resource directory name"

What to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am answering my own question :-).

It's **values-en-rSK**, -r is Region.

Answer (score 1):

For Slovakia - Slovak location you have to create folder

```
res/values-sk-rSK
```

Working in Android 2.3 and >